# Artifactory CLI - Jfrog - How to get binary Hash code (SHA1, SHA256) through jfrog CLI

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Is there a way to get the binary HASH code(SHA1, SHA256) from artifactory through jfrog cli?
Or at least to download only binaries with specific HASH.

I tried to use the props like below, but it does not work.

jfrog rt download --props "sha1=506438fbfc4a029ffee8b001fdce3c2cbd5541ec --server-id af-server.com afrepo/test_repo/test.txt

[image: SHA-1 for one artifatory artifact]"

Answer (score 2):

an Artifact sha-1 is not a property but but an item.field.
You can therefore query an artifact by sha1 using the field name (it is actually "actual_sha1") using AQL.
You can use AQL with curl (see some examples [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language)) or with the CLI using spec files (examples [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs))

(Note that the AQL structure is slightly different between spec files and curl)

With all that said, your sha1 search example would look like this.

CLI command:

```
jfrog rt s --spec="/MyPath/MySpecFile"
```

Spec file

```
{  "files": [
{
  "aql": {
    "items.find": 
                  {
      "repo": "my-local-repo",
      "actual_sha1": {"$eq": "6aebc7357ba46916aab5e9d29b3f8e7180cd7089"}
                  }
         }
}]}
```